# How to simulate AppLocale behavior for non-Unicode software?

Tags: windows, delphi, unicode, delphi-2009

I am writing software (Delphi 2009 Unicode project) which depends on third party library (.dll).

The library is working fine in English language but when I switch the language of application to Russian some characters are not shown correctly. (I can see ?????).
(Application uses several languages - most of them is working fine but especially Russian customers can see this bug).

I found out when I run the software with AppLocale (Russian language) everything works fine.
Also if in Windows Regional settings I set **Language for non-Unicode applications** to Russian I can see the characters correctly.

*How can I achieve the same with code?*

As I do not have sources for the library I cannot modify it. I suppose I need to initialize my software the same way as AppLocale do.

Something like calling SetThreadLocale() in application to affect whole application - and also the library.

There is no problem to write C/C++/C# library if this cannot be achieved directly in Delphi.

Comment: You are probably screwed because it sounds like the library is an ANSI library. But only you know those details.

Comment: Yes, you are right - but it works fine with AppLocale. All I want is to do the same thing AppLocale does (but in code).

Comment: Not possible I think. Stop using ANSI and start using Unicode.

Comment: I imagine it to be doing a lot of api hooking.